# Parent to child class static variables remains unchanged

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the first random is stays the same for example its 50 the child class text will be 50 and after another random for example is 45 it should be 50 + 45 not replace the value with 45

Parent class

```
    public class BattleSystemScript : GameManagerRevamped
   {
      static public int CoinsRandom;
      public TextMeshProUGUI Coins;

         void Start()
         {  
           CoinsRandom = Random.Range(30, 50);
           Coins.text = CoinsRandom.ToString();
         } 
  }
```

Child class

```
public class PlayerValues : BattleSystemScript
{
  int CoinsRandomValue;
  public TextMeshProUGUI PlayerCoins;         
       void Start()
       {
        CoinsRandomValue += CoinsRandom;
        PlayerCoins.text = CoinsRandomValue.ToString();
       }
}
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is the one expected if you create a new instance of `PlayerValues`. Also, that logic is pretty weird, it doesn't make sense for PlayerValues to extend BattleSystemScript

Comment: What should I do ??

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: in the child class Text the value is just getting replaced instead of incrementing for example the first random value is 50 and the next random value is 45 it should be 95 not replace the 50

Comment: Never mind just solved my problem XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parent `Start` a `virtual` method

```
public class BattleSystemScript : GameManagerRevamped
{
    static public int CoinsRandom;
    public TextMeshProUGUI Coins;

    protected virtual void Start()
    {  
        CoinsRandom = Random.Range(30, 50);
        Coins.text = CoinsRandom.ToString();
    } 
}
```

And `override` it in the child class in order to extend it

```
public class PlayerValues : BattleSystemScript
{
    int CoinsRandomValue;
    public TextMeshProUGUI PlayerCoins;         
    protected override void Start()
    {
        // call to the parent Start
        base.Start();

        CoinsRandomValue += CoinsRandom;
        PlayerCoins.text = CoinsRandomValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just had to make the child class static too lol

--->

```
static public int CoinsRandomValue;
static public int DiamondsValues;
static public int ExperienceRandomValue;
```

Comment: Static is not the correct solution. Static means that there is exactly 1 "copy" of that variable, regardless of how many times you instantiate your code and they all share it.

Comment: But it does the job that I'm looking for :'(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods The Q&A is tagged Java, but the same logic applies to C#.